# How to sed two words in a line and add before and after?

Tags: bash, sed

I was curious to know if there is a better way to `sed` two words and add a line before and after them.

I learned how from [grymoire](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-60) but I wanted to know if there was a better way to do:

```
#!/bin/sh
sed '
/foo/,/bar/ {
i\
Add this line before
a\
Add this line after
}'
```

What I am trying to do is find two words on one line, in this case `foo` and `bar` and then add something on the line before and the line after.

If its not to much trouble or off-topic, can some recommend in the comments a few other sites to read on `sed` other than grymoire?

Comment: I assume you've looked at `man sed`

Comment: @netinept Yes that would be correct but I was hoping for something more on studies and the capabilities of `sed`.

Comment: Please show some sample input and what you want the output to look like

Comment: For more documentation, there's the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) which has an Examples section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

awk is easier, IMO

```
awk '
    /foo/ && /bar/ {
        print "Add this line before"
        print
        print "Add this line after"
        next
    }
    {print}
' file
```